# Yosemite crashes on startup with henge dock

Tags: macos, dock, crash

I am running a 13' macbook pro early 2015 inside a Henge dock (HD03VA13MBPR). It works perfectly despite the fact that on reboot the system will crash after login credentials have been entered. I have to take it out to reboot and then put it back in.

Is there a logfile where I can check what is causing the crash? Install has been made via timemachine, where I had yosemite on my earlier mac book pro.

This is the crash report:

> Anonymous UUID:       A8E0FC6E-AE34-78D9-5708-DE139500B4EF

Wed May 13 20:37:10 2015

*** Panic Report ***
panic(cpu 2 caller 0xffffff8008e17cc2): Kernel trap at 0xffffff7f8ae9db06, type 14=page fault, registers:
CR0: 0x0000000080010033, CR2: 0xffffff89a6803fe8, CR3: 0x000000044fed3004, CR4: 0x00000000003627e0
RAX: 0x00000000ffffffff, RBX: 0x00000000e00002bc, RCX: 0xffffff7f8aec2154, RDX: 0xffffff802a668600
RSP: 0xffffff81f357b820, RBP: 0xffffff81f357b820, RSI: 0x00000000ffffffff, RDI: 0xffffff81a6802000
R8:  0xffffff802a668600, R9:  0xffffff81f357b9d0, R10: 0xffffff7f89f87950, R11: 0xffffff81f357bb80
R12: 0xffffff81a6802000, R13: 0xffffff8029227ab4, R14: 0xffffff802a668600, R15: 0x0000000000000002
RFL: 0x0000000000010297, RIP: 0xffffff7f8ae9db06, CS:  0x0000000000000008, SS:  0x0000000000000010
Fault CR2: 0xffffff89a6803fe8, Error code: 0x0000000000000000, Fault CPU: 0x2

Backtrace (CPU 2), Frame : Return Address
0xffffff81f357b4d0 : 0xffffff8008d2bda1 
0xffffff81f357b550 : 0xffffff8008e17cc2 
0xffffff81f357b710 : 0xffffff8008e34b73 
0xffffff81f357b730 : 0xffffff7f8ae9db06 
0xffffff81f357b820 : 0xffffff7f8aeae8f0 
0xffffff81f357b860 : 0xffffff7f8aec2164 
0xffffff81f357b8b0 : 0xffffff7f8aec239d 
0xffffff81f357b8d0 : 0xffffff80092d41ce 
0xffffff81f357b910 : 0xffffff7f8aec2408 
0xffffff81f357b960 : 0xffffff7f8ae78d74 
0xffffff81f357b980 : 0xffffff7f8ae78eb1 
0xffffff81f357ba00 : 0xffffff7f8b2ca5c9 
0xffffff81f357ba60 : 0xffffff80092d41ce 
0xffffff81f357baa0 : 0xffffff7f8b2ca9d8 
0xffffff81f357baf0 : 0xffffff7f8ae78eb1 
0xffffff81f357bb70 : 0xffffff7f8ae7884e 
0xffffff81f357bbc0 : 0xffffff80092ff0c3 
0xffffff81f357bd00 : 0xffffff8008de21e7 
0xffffff81f357be10 : 0xffffff8008d3000c 
0xffffff81f357be40 : 0xffffff8008d149f3 
0xffffff81f357be90 : 0xffffff8008d2531d 
0xffffff81f357bf10 : 0xffffff8008e031ea 
0xffffff81f357bfb0 : 0xffffff8008e35396 
      Kernel Extensions in backtrace:
         com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.10.22)[44D7223C-9628-3FEA-A3B8-27DE9E1CE0C3]@0xffffff7f8ae78000->0xffffff7f8ae7dfff
         com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer(10.0.6)[BD924979-4EEE-345B-95A3-59BC631819CD]@0xffffff7f8ae7e000->0xffffff7f8aed1fff
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f89537000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f89eca000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2(156.14)[BE7D765B-49C1-34F9-B75E-3EAF8A4062A3]@0xffffff7f8adfb000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily(31)[781C9DD1-4CE9-3AEB-85EA-D420CEC18916]@0xffffff7f89a6c000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.10.22)[44D7223C-9628-3FEA-A3B8-27DE9E1CE0C3]@0xffffff7f8ae78000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7f89f63000
         com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy(3.7.7)[59E7CF6C-C2D1-3FFC-A122-DB048907FB67]@0xffffff7f8b2c6000->0xffffff7f8b2ccfff
            dependency: com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl(3.10.22)[61967104-88AF-3605-82F5-A480A2800A78]@0xffffff7f8b2a2000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily(1.4)[70E2B65E-A91A-3522-A1A0-79FD63EABB4C]@0xffffff7f89eca000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily(2.9)[52E715FC-521D-3869-B2EA-5228FA4BEA34]@0xffffff7f89537000
            dependency: com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily(2.4.1)[82EAD591-67E3-39CB-A232-A8095CA30E92]@0xffffff7f89f63000
            dependency: com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl(3.10.22)[44D7223C-9628-3FEA-A3B8-27DE9E1CE0C3]@0xffffff7f8ae78000

BSD process name corresponding to current thread: displaypolicyd

Mac OS version:
14D136

Kernel version:
Darwin Kernel Version 14.3.0: Mon Mar 23 11:59:05 PDT 2015; root:xnu-2782.20.48~5/RELEASE_X86_64
Kernel UUID: 4B3A11F4-77AA-3D27-A22D-81A1BC5B504D
Kernel slide:     0x0000000008a00000
Kernel text base: 0xffffff8008c00000
__HIB  text base: 0xffffff8008b00000
System model name: MacBookPro12,1 (Mac-E43C1C25D4880AD6)

System uptime in nanoseconds: 23730544570
last loaded kext at 12980188722: com.cisco.kext.acsock  1.1.0 (addr 0xffffff7f8b4c6000, size 57344)
loaded kexts:
com.cisco.kext.acsock   1.1.0
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetAdp  4.3.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxNetFlt  4.3.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxUSB 4.3.26
org.virtualbox.kext.VBoxDrv 4.3.26
net.sf.tuntaposx.tun    1.0
net.sf.tuntaposx.tap    1.0
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboardUSB   8.2
com.microsoft.driver.MicrosoftKeyboard  8.2
com.asix.driver.ax88179-178a    1.4.0
com.protech.NoSleep 1.4.0
com.apple.filesystems.autofs    3.0
com.apple.driver.AudioAUUC  1.70
com.apple.driver.ApplePlatformEnabler   2.2.0d4
com.apple.driver.AGPM   110.19.5
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformShim    1.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothSerialManager    4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.AppleOSXWatchdog   1
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsDevicePolicy  3.7.7
com.apple.driver.AppleUpstreamUserClient    3.6.1
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCDC    4.3.3b1
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothUSBDFU   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.BroadcomBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport 4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.SCSITaskUserClient  3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAHardwareConfigDriver   272.18
com.apple.driver.AppleHDA   272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOUserEthernet  1.0.1
com.apple.Dont_Steal_Mac_OS_X   7.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleHWAccess  1
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphics  10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMuxControl    3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleLPC   1.7.3
com.apple.driver.AppleHV    1
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklight 170.7.4
com.apple.driver.ACPI_SMC_PlatformPlugin    1.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelSlowAdaptiveClocking 4.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleFIVRDriver    4.1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelBDWGraphicsFramebuffer   10.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleMCCSControl   1.2.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSMCLMU    2.0.7d0
com.apple.driver.AppleCameraInterface   5.33.0
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltIP 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBCardReader 3.5.5
com.apple.driver.CoreStorageFsck    471.20.7
com.apple.driver.AppleFileSystemDriver  3.0.1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeDataless 1.0.0d1
com.apple.AppleFSCompression.AppleFSCompressionTypeZlib 1.0.0d1
com.apple.BootCache 36
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBHub    705.4.2
com.apple.driver.XsanFilter 404
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIBlockStorage  2.7.1
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIPassThrough   1.0.3
com.apple.driver.AppleAHCIPort  3.1.2
com.apple.driver.AppleTopCaseHIDEventDriver 67
com.apple.driver.AirPort.Brcm4360   930.37.3
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBXHCI   710.4.11
com.apple.driver.AppleSmartBatteryManager   161.0.0
com.apple.driver.AppleRTC   2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIButtons   3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleHPET  1.8
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBIOS    2.1
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIEC    3.1
com.apple.driver.AppleAPIC  1.7
com.apple.nke.applicationfirewall   161
com.apple.security.quarantine   3
com.apple.security.TMSafetyNet  8
com.apple.kext.triggers 1.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBAudio  295.23
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBHIDDriver  705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothHostControllerUSBTransport   4.3.4f4
com.apple.driver.DspFuncLib 272.18
com.apple.kext.OSvKernDSPLib    1.15
com.apple.iokit.IOBluetoothFamily   4.3.4f4
com.apple.iokit.IOSurface   97.4
com.apple.driver.AppleGraphicsControl   3.10.22
com.apple.driver.AppleBacklightExpert   1.1.0
com.apple.iokit.IONDRVSupport   2.4.1
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginLegacy 1.0.0
com.apple.driver.X86PlatformPlugin  1.0.0
com.apple.driver.IOPlatformPluginFamily 5.9.1d7
com.apple.iokit.IOSlowAdaptiveClockingFamily    1.0.0
com.apple.AppleGraphicsDeviceControl    3.10.22
com.apple.iokit.IOAcceleratorFamily2    156.14
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusController   1.0.13d1
com.apple.driver.AppleSMC   3.1.9
com.apple.driver.AppleSMBusPCI  1.0.12d1
com.apple.driver.AppleHDAController 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOGraphicsFamily    2.4.1
com.apple.iokit.IOHDAFamily 272.18
com.apple.iokit.IOAudioFamily   203.3
com.apple.vecLib.kext   1.2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssUART 2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOSerialFamily  11
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltEDMSink    4.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPOutAdapter   4.0.6
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBUserClient 705.4.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIBlockCommandsDevice   3.7.5
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBMassStorageClass   3.7.2
com.apple.iokit.IOSCSIArchitectureModelFamily   3.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBMergeNub   705.4.0
com.apple.driver.AppleUSBComposite  705.4.9
com.apple.driver.CoreStorage    471.20.7
com.apple.iokit.IOAHCIFamily    2.7.5
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPInAdapter    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltDPAdapterFamily    4.0.6
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltPCIDownAdapter 2.0.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHIDKeyboard   176.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPIHIDDriver    41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleMultitouchDriver  263.9.1
com.apple.driver.AppleThunderboltNHI    3.1.7
com.apple.iokit.IOThunderboltFamily 4.2.2
com.apple.iokit.IO80211Family   730.60
com.apple.driver.mDNSOffloadUserClient  1.0.1b8
com.apple.iokit.IONetworkingFamily  3.2
com.apple.driver.AppleHSSPISupport  41.3
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssSpiController    2.0.56
com.apple.iokit.IOUSBFamily 720.4.4
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssGspi 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssI2C  2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleIntelLpssDmac 2.0.56
com.apple.driver.AppleEFINVRAM  2.0
com.apple.driver.AppleEFIRuntime    2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOHIDFamily 2.0.0
com.apple.iokit.IOSMBusFamily   1.1
com.apple.security.sandbox  300.0
com.apple.kext.AppleMatch   1.0.0d1
com.apple.driver.AppleKeyStore  2
com.apple.driver.AppleMobileFileIntegrity   1.0.5
com.apple.driver.AppleCredentialManager 1.0
com.apple.driver.DiskImages 396
com.apple.iokit.IOStorageFamily 2.0
com.apple.iokit.IOReportFamily  31
com.apple.driver.AppleFDEKeyStore   28.30
com.apple.driver.AppleACPIPlatform  3.1
com.apple.iokit.IOPCIFamily 2.9
com.apple.iokit.IOACPIFamily    1.4
com.apple.kec.Libm  1
com.apple.kec.pthread   1
com.apple.kec.corecrypto    1.0
Model: MacBookPro12,1, BootROM MBP121.0167.B00, 2 processors, Intel Core i5, 2.9 GHz, 16 GB, SMC 2.28f6
Graphics: Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Intel Iris Graphics 6100, Built-In
Memory Module: BANK 0/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464232333241314D412D4A442D460000
Memory Module: BANK 1/DIMM0, 8 GB, DDR3, 1867 MHz, 0x02FE, 0x4544464232333241314D412D4A442D460000
AirPort: spairport_wireless_card_type_airport_extreme (0x14E4, 0x133), Broadcom BCM43xx 1.0 (7.15.166.24.3)
Bluetooth: Version 4.3.4f4 15601, 3 services, 27 devices, 1 incoming serial ports
Serial ATA Device: APPLE SSD SM0512G, 500,28 GB
USB Device: Internal Memory Card Reader
USB Device: Bluetooth USB Host Controller
Thunderbolt Bus: MacBook Pro, Apple Inc., 27.1

Comment: In your Utility Folder open the Console app, there you will find the logs.

Answer (score 1):

In your Utility Folder open the Console app.

In the all messages view scroll back to the time when you logged in and take a look what is it reporting. (or paste it here (some 50 lines) for us to look at)

You can also use the Terminal app (also in your Utility folder) and copy paste following to see which app crashed.

```
ps aux | grep -w Z
```